# Flutter Video Functionality not working in release mode. However it is working in debug mode

Tags: flutter

I am creating a simple app that will show a button in home screen to record video. And once the button is clicked, it will go to VideoRecorder class and directly camera will open and we can press buttons to start recording video.
So when I run the project directly in emulator or a real device in debug mode, then the camera is loading and I can make the video.
But when I use the release APK, and then install it into the emulator or device, then on clicking "Record Video" button on home page , it starts showing me a grey screen.

Can you please tell me what is the issue?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class RecordVideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecordVideoScreenState createState() => _RecordVideoScreenState();
}

class _RecordVideoScreenState extends State<RecordVideoScreen> {
  late CameraController _controllers;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  String _selectedVideoPath = '';
  bool _isRecording = false;
  late CameraDescription _currentCamera;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeControllerFuture = _initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final firstCamera = cameras.first;
    _currentCamera = firstCamera;

    _controllers = CameraController(
      firstCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
    );
    await _controllers.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _toggleRecording() async {
    if (_isRecording) {
      final recordedVideo = await _controllers.stopVideoRecording();
      setState(() {
        _isRecording = false;
        _selectedVideoPath = recordedVideo.path; // Store the path for preview
        print("Muskan : recorded path - " + recordedVideo.path);
      });
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => VideoPreviewAndUploadScreen(
            videoPath: _selectedVideoPath,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      await _initializeControllerFuture;
      await _controllers.startVideoRecording();
      setState(() {
        _isRecording = true;
        _selectedVideoPath =
            ''; // Clear the selected video path when recording starts
      });
    }
  }

  void _toggleCamera() async {
    final List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

    if (cameras.length < 2) {
      // Only one camera is available, no need to toggle
      return;
    }

    final newCamera = _getOppositeCamera(_currentCamera, cameras);

    if (_controllers != null) {
      await _controllers.dispose();
    }

    setState(() {
      _currentCamera = newCamera;
      _controllers = CameraController(
        _currentCamera,
        ResolutionPreset.medium,
        imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420,
      );
      _controllers.initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
    });
  }

  CameraDescription _getOppositeCamera(
      CameraDescription currentCamera, List<CameraDescription> allCameras) {
    return allCameras.firstWhere(
        (camera) => camera.lensDirection != currentCamera.lensDirection);
  }

  Future<void> _pickVideoFromGallery() async {
    final pickedVideo =
        await _imagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedVideo != null) {
      print("Muskan - gallery path - " + pickedVideo.path);
      setState(() {
        _selectedVideoPath = pickedVideo.path;
      });
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => VideoPreviewAndUploadScreen(
            videoPath: _selectedVideoPath,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllers.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_controllers.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CameraPreview(_controllers), // Wrap with Expanded
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _toggleRecording,
                  child: Icon(
                    _isRecording ? Icons.stop : Icons.fiber_manual_record,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _pickVideoFromGallery,
                  child: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _toggleCamera,
                  child: Icon(Icons.flip_camera_android),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}

class VideoPreviewAndUploadScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String videoPath;

  VideoPreviewAndUploadScreen({required this.videoPath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: VideoPreviewWidget(videoPath: videoPath),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // Upload video logic here
              await _uploadVideo(videoPath);
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Video uploaded successfully'),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.upload),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context); // Return to previous screen
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.cancel),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  Future<void> _uploadVideo(String videoPath) async {
    // Your upload logic here, similar to the _saveAnswer function
    // Upload video to Firebase Storage and save the download URL in Firestore
  }
}

class VideoPreviewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoPath;

  VideoPreviewWidget({required this.videoPath});

  @override
  _VideoPreviewWidgetState createState() => _VideoPreviewWidgetState();
}

class _VideoPreviewWidgetState extends State<VideoPreviewWidget> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.videoPath));
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.play();
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Error initializing video player: $error');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: _controller.value.isInitialized
          ? FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // Adjust this as needed
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _controller.value.size.width,
                height: _controller.value.size.height,
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              ),
            )
          : CircularProgressIndicator(), // You can use any loading indicator here
    );
  }
}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml file , I have added these :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I tried to add permissions in my AndroidManifest File.

I tried to toggle android:hardwareAccelerated value between true an false.

I tried to do 'flutter clean' then 'flutter build apk'

I tried to uninstall the app from device, and then only install the fresh one.